# Combination question: Choose number of people on a committee without using complement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For the question

> The $11$ men and $10$ women of the Math Club (including Jack and Jill) need to form a committee consisting of $4$ people. In how many ways can this be done so that there are the same number of women as men, but Jack and Jill are not both on the committee.

I know I can do this question as a complement in that I select total number of combinations possible when there are no restrictions other than equal number of men and women ${11 \choose2} \cdot {10\choose 2}$ and subtract from it the combinations possible when Jack and Jill are on the committee ${9\choose1} \cdot {10\choose1} $ for a total of $2,385$ combination

But I want to try to do it the other way where I list out the combinations, but I am not getting the same answer. I am over counting. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

**Edit** I have updated for the earlier error based on @vladz comments

1. Combinations when Jack is on the committee but not Jill $$ 10 \cdot {9\choose2} = 360$$
2. Combinations when Jill is on the committee but not Jack $$ {10 \choose 2} \cdot 9 = 405$$
3. Combinations when neither Jill nor Jack is on the committee $$ {10 \choose 2} \cdot {9 \choose 2} = 1620$$

For which the total is $360 + 405 + 1620 = 2,385$

Comment: You are including 11 men and 10 women in 1 and 2 respectively. You need to include 10 men and 9 women, removing Jack and Jill from the population respectively

Comment: For part 1, I was thinking that Jack is included so you have 10 men left to choose 1 from and 10 women to pick 2 from. For part 2, it 's choosing 2 men from 11 and and since Jill is included I am have 9 options left for women to  choose form, which is I think what you are saying

Comment: For 1 you only have 9 women to choose from as Jill is not included

Comment: After you have edited your question, the second $2,385$ looks pretty much the same as the first $2,385$. I think, the only wrong thing left is the $460$ in the last line.